# how can I add a JSONP endpoing for WCF Ria Services to enable cross-domain calls?

Tags: jsonp, wcf-ria-services

I'm aware that WCF RIA Services has a Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory that I can use to enable JSON.
I need to enable cross-domain calls via JSONP. Is there an existing DomainServiceEndpointFactory that will accomplish this?

Comment: The crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled property of the webHttpBinding is what needs enabled. Is there a way to do this with a behavior when the EndPointFactory is creating the service instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to do this - I overrode JsonEndpointFactory and tinkered with the binding in there, then added an endpoint using the new class.

```
namespace Bodge
{
    public class JsonPEndpointFactory : JsonEndpointFactory
    {
        public override IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint> CreateEndpoints(DomainServiceDescription description, DomainServiceHost serviceHost)
        {
            IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint> endPoints = base.CreateEndpoints(description, serviceHost);
            foreach (ServiceEndpoint endPoint in endPoints)
            {
                if (endPoint.Binding is WebHttpBinding)
                {
                    ((WebHttpBinding)endPoint.Binding).CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true;
                }
            }

            return endPoints;
        }
    }
}

  <endpoints>
    <add name="JSONP" type="Bodge.JsonPEndpointFactory, Bodge, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
  </endpoints>
```

Then access your service with the endpoint and the callback query param e.g.
http://blah/service.svc/JSONP/GetStuff?callback=callbackname

Hope that helps,
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting in comments isn't great, so for future reference here are the required usings and assemblies.

Thanks very much, that's exactly what I needed!for future reference, these are the using statements:

Namespaces:

```
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;
using Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
```

Assemblies

NETFX 4.0

```
System.ServiceModel
System.ServiceModel.Web
```

[WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP2 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27227)

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server
```

[WCF RIA Services Toolkit (September 2011)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26939)

```
Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
```