# Consuming an authenticated RIA Domain Service via JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth, jsonp, wcf-ria-services

I'm writing an HTML5/JavaScript application that needs to consume data from an existing WCF RIA Services Domain Service. Requests will always be cross-domain so I have added a JSONP endpoint onto the service using the solution I posted in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823649/how-can-i-add-a-jsonp-endpoing-for-wcf-ria-services-to-enable-cross-domain-calls).

Using *jQuery.ajax()* I can successfully retrieve data from the service when authentication is off. With authentication on I get this error:

> *Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.*

This is by-design behaviour so I need a workaround!

The possible solution I'm looking at is to try and use **OAuth**. My current thinking is to use the JavaScript library and DotNetOpenAuth code referred to on [oauth.net](http://oauth.net/code/). I'm hoping to implement the service in a seperate server instance with OAuth authentication (instead of forms/windows) and tack on the relevant request headers to my jQuery calls.

So my reason for posting is, does this sound reasonable and is this the best approach? And if so does anyone have any experience, tips or samples they want to share? :)

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: I too am very interested in this. I've been fooling around trying to integrate OAuth into the authentication scheme generated by the Silverlight Business Application solution template. I'm a bit puzzled as to why anyone would choose script when they could have C# but that's a jihaad for another day. It's come to me that SL is delivered embedded in a web page giving me a chance to dance the OAUTH two-step and get a token. Now I'm staring at the screen wondering how to apply the acquired token to security in RIA. Can you be persuaded to share your thoughts on the whole RIA with tokens thing?

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm afraid I didn't get around to finishing this project or implementing the idea I had so have no more advice. Hopefully someone out there on SO can help.